Movie where large sinkholes appear in a city
About 5 years ago I watched a movie which started off with a large hole appearing in the street. As the film progresses, more holes appear.
The main characters soon realise there is a HUGE hollow area just under the town and they need to fill it before the ground gives way and the town collapses into it.
I remember there is a scene where there is a carnival (possibly Mardi Gras) and people are dancing, stamping the ground etc which makes the ground cave in.
The main characters daughter is at this carnival.
At the end they try to fill the hole with foam filler stuff.
Does anyone know the name of this film please?

Yep, looks like you're looking for On Hostile Ground starring John Corbett.

Corbett stars as Matt Andrews, a geologist who is asked to investigate why there have been two large sinkholes affecting the city of New Orleans. Jessica Steen plays his girlfriend Allison Beauchamp, assistant to the Mayor, who has to decide whether the problems with the sinkholes will spread far enough to require that the remainder of Mardi Gras be cancelled, which would be an economic disaster to the city.

As you can see, it involves sink holes threatening to destroy New Orleans during Mardi Gras, as you say in the question.

Thats it... ty :)
